# New-PSSession: This parameter set requires WSMan, and no supported WSMan client library was found. CENTOS/RHEL 8

Tags: linux, powershell, centos, rhel8, wsman

So im working on server and i have installed powershell on it and when i try to run this command

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

i get the following error

***New-PSSession: This parameter set requires WSMan, and no supported WSMan client library was found. WSMan is either not installed or unavailable for this system.***

**Tried installing the WSman module with these commands still didnt fix it

Install-Module -Name PSWSMan -Force

Install-WSMan**

```
 Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.1.4
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.4
OS                             Linux 4.18.0-305.10.2.el8_4.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon J…
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

i am a complete beginner to this any guidance will be very helpful

Comment: Does this  help - https://linuxhint.com/install_powershell_centos/

Comment: @RamanSailopal powershell works fine all commands work ,But after installing WSman Module to connect to microsoft exchange  ,still get the error saying WSman module not found